# Sass always caches regardless of the setting - how to stop this?

Tags: sinatra, sass

No matter what setting I give Sass for caching, a cache is still created:

```
# in sinatra
set :sass, { :cache => false }

# after running the app
$ ls -al
drwxr-xr-x   3 iainuser  iainuser    102 20 Jan 17:33 .sass-cache
```

Is there something else I need to do to stop the caches being created? Any insight is much appreciated.

SASS v3.1.12, Sinatra v1.3.1

Comment: Why do you need to disable the cache?

Comment: @maxbeatty During development I want to be certain that I'm seeing the latest version of a file. Sometimes I'm having to refresh several times to get that, so I'd like it disabled.

Comment: that's a browser issue, not a sass cache issue. Have you tried using a tool like [Live Reload](http://livereload.com/)? Every time you save a change to your Sass, it can compile the CSS and refresh the page for you. Changed my life.

Comment: @maxbeatty Hmmm, I disagree. It's a sass cache issue because I tell it not to create cache and it does. Thanks for the tip, I was looking at Guard for that earlier.